# Xpath expression for a special tag

Tags: html, regex, xpath, attributes

I have these tags in html that I would like some help to distinguish them from each other:

```
<tr data-row="0" data-row-quote="_" class="  

    even

">

<tr data-row="3" data-row-quote="_" class="sometext 

    odd

">
```

In the above tags, I like to include data-row-quote="_" and the class attribute that separate the two types.

**[EDIT]**

Suppose I find the tr collection that satisfies the proposed xpath query by using HttpAgilityPack like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(res.Html);
HtmlNodeCollection trs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@data-row-quote=\"_\" and not(starts-with(@class, 'sometext'))]");
```

Let's say I am interested in the first and last nodes and would like to get their tds respectively. Can I do it this way:

```
doc.LoadHtml(trs[0].InnerHtml);
HtmlNodeCollection tds1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td");
doc.LoadHtml(trs[trs.Count-1].InnerHtml);
HtmlNodeCollection tds2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td");
```

Any idea?

Comment: Don't worry. I found it. In order to do it right, we need to construct a new doc before using it:  doc = new HttpDocument();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@data-row-quote` and `@class` to check the attribute values:

```
//tr[@data-row-quote = "_" and not(contains(@class, "sometext"))]
//tr[@data-row-quote = "_" and contains(@class, "sometext")]
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I like to consider "odd"/"even" as non-specific text which can be expressed as regex.The most distinguishable feature for the class attribute is before the "odd"/"even".  In example 1, there is no text but empty space prior to "even" but in example 2 there is some text. How can I differentiate the two by means similar to regex?

Comment: @Ben okay, added an example, check it out.

Comment: Will something like this work: //tr[@data-row-quote = "_" and starts-with(@class, " ")]?

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably use `contains()` and `normalize-space()` instead of `starts-with()`.

Comment: ...in which case, to prevent false positives, it should be `contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), concat(' ', 'sometext', ' '))`.